# Перезагрузка базы данных

Tags: visual-basic, visual-studio

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите пожалуйста - как перезагрузить базу данных для применения внесенных изменений? Допустим, я внес в базу некоторые данные. Но они сразу не появляются на других формах. 
Для этого я создал кнопку обновления базы, с кодом (4it - это название базы):

```
    Me._4itDataSet.Reset()
```

Но это помогло лишь частично - так как некоторые таблицы не перезагружаются. Тогда добавил еще немного кода:

```
    Me._4itDataSet.Reset()
    Me.Виды_работTableAdapter.Fill(Me._4itDataSet.Виды_работ)
    Me.ДоговорTableAdapter.Fill(Me._4itDataSet.Договор)
    Me.ИсполнительTableAdapter.Fill(Me._4itDataSet.Исполнитель)
    Me.ПользователиTableAdapter.Fill(Me._4itDataSet.Пользователи)
    Me.Физические_лицаTableAdapter.Fill(Me._4itDataSet.Физические_лица)
```

Все равно не помогло... Так вот вопрос - как перезагрузить базу данных?

Заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: Me.Физические_лицаTableAdapter.Fill(Me._4itDataSet.Физические_лица) - вот это да! мой мозг протестуе!

Comment: Обычный код на загрузку данных в датагрид, создается одновременно с перетаскиванием датагрида из датасурз на форму. Что не так?

Comment: Русско-английские названия переменных :)

Comment: Ааа) Но мне так проще - лучше запоминается)На русском - названия таблиц, на инглише - все остальное)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена - строчка

```
         Me._4itDataSet.Reset()
```

была абсолютно лишней, достаточно основного кода

```
      Me.Виды_работTableAdapter.Fill(Me._4itDataSet.Виды_работ)
      Me.ДоговорTableAdapter.Fill(Me._4itDataSet.Договор)
      Me.ИсполнительTableAdapter.Fill(Me._4itDataSet.Исполнитель)
      Me.ПользователиTableAdapter.Fill(Me._4itDataSet.Пользователи)
      Me.Физические_лицаTableAdapter.Fill(Me._4itDataSet.Физические_лица)
```